# Как узнать пользователя (или его ip), запустившего скрипт Python на сервере локальной сети?

Tags: python, windows, lan

Есть локальная сеть, в ней сервер на *Windows* (обычный компьютер). На этом сервере есть скрипт (в виде *exe* - *cxfreeze*).

Есть ли какой-то механизм в *питоне*, с помощью которого можно узнать, с какого компьютера в локальной сети запускали скрипт?

Answer (score 2):

```
import socket
print socket.gethostname() # host name
print socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) # IPv4

import getpass
print getpass.getuser() # user name
```